# ArcObjects ISQLSyntax with Oracle DB esriSQL_DelimitedIdentifierPrefix issue

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, query

New to stack exchange, heading over from the esri forums, it is great!

I am trying to produce a query that I can use across all workspaces, naturally using [ISQLSyntax](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000850000000). The problem I'm having is that when using esriSQL_DelimitedIdentifierPrefix on a Oracle SDE instance it is returning a speech mark, whereas I'd expect it to return a blank string. When I use this code on a FileGDB or an MDB it works as expected, but on SDE I get the error:

Underlying DBMS error[ORA-00904: "table.field_name": invalid identifier][OWNER.TABLE]

The error goes away if I remove the prefix and suffix, so there are no typos in the query. I don't want to do a select case SDE because it seems against the point of having ISQLSyntax.

Any Ideas?

```
Dim Prefix As string, Suffix As string
Dim upper As String, sQualColName As String
Prefix = pSQLSyntax.GetSpecialCharacter(esriSQLSpecialCharacters.esriSQL_DelimitedIdentifierPrefix)
Suffix = pSQLSyntax.GetSpecialCharacter(esriSQLSpecialCharacters.esriSQL_DelimitedIdentifierSuffix)

sQualColName = pSQLSyntax.QualifyColumnName("table", "field_name")

sVal = Prefix & sQualColName & Suffix & " = " & Chr(39) & Trim(strFindString).ToUpper & Chr(39)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried the same thing in Oracle 11g, it worked fine. The Prefix and Suffix are double quotes just like FGDBs, but I believe they are optional in Oracle.

The difference seems to be that when you use double-quotes around your column identifiers that it becomes case-sensitive, so ensure all column names you write in code are the correct case.

`QualifyColumnName` doesn't correct the case for you.

Comment: Many thanks blah, you are right about the case. One further thing, when using the prefix I found that using the fully qualified name no longer worked (i.e TABLE.COLUMN). Cheers for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Don't use it like that.

When you get a table name from the db and you want its parts, use [ParseTableName](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/ISQLSyntax_ParseTableName.htm).

When doing the opposite (i.e you want a fully qualified table name from its parts) use [QualifyTableName](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/ISQLSyntax_QualifyTableName.htm)

The same applies for columns ([ParseColumnName](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/ISQLSyntax_ParseColumnName.htm), [QualifyColumnName](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/ISQLSyntax_QualifyColumnName.htm))

No need to append anything before or after.

Comment: Does QualifyColumnName add prefix/suffix itself? E.g. brackets for personal GDB, double-quotes for SHP and FGDB, etc. I can't remember but I don't think it does. Sounds like the goal is to be able to write a where clause.

Comment: blah is correct, I'm not after the parts of the field name or the combined and QualifyColumnName does not bring back the delimitors. What I need is for the esriSQL_DelimitedIdentifierSuffix to return [ for Personal Geodatabase, " for File and then a blank string for SDE. The goal is to write a where clause with the correct delimiters, which I think this should do. It just doesn't return the correct value for SDE.

Comment: It occurred to me that it might be because I was returning the value to a char and chars can't be blank. I tested with a string and it still doesn't work